# I'm trying to pull a value from an array but it's only pulling the first value and I'm not sure why?

Tags: vb.net, autodesk-inventor

I'm using Autodesk Inventor with Visual Basic and I'm trying to display a value in a box. The values all display except one. The value fractionDisplay(thicknessDisplay) keeps showing 3/16 (which is the first value in my fractionDisplay() array) in the box. Why won't it show the other values based on the thicknessDisplay number being set to anything besides 0?

Here is my code:

```
Dim erpNumber() As String = {"PA0001", "PA0002", "PA0003", "PA0004", "PA0006", "PC0003", "PC0004", "PC0005", "PC0006", "PC0007", "PC0008", "PC0009", "PC0010", "PC0011"}
Dim fractionDisplay() As String = {"3/16", "1/4", "5/16", "3/8", "1/8", "1/2", "5/8", "3/4", "1", "1 1/4", "1 1/2", "2", "2 1/2", "3"}

stockNumberValue = erpNumber(plateThickness)

iProperties.Value("Project", "Description") = fractionDisplay(thicknessDisplay) & """" & " X " & Length & """" & " X " & Width & """" & " 100XF BURNOUT"

If Thickness = 0.1875 Then
    plateThickness = 0
    thicknessDisplay = 0
ElseIf Thickness = 0.25 Then
    plateThickness = 1
    thicknessDisplay = 1
ElseIf Thickness = 0.3125 Then
    plateThickness = 2
    thicknessDisplay = 2
ElseIf Thickness = 0.375 Then
    plateThickness = 3
    thicknessDisplay = 3
ElseIf Thickness = 0.125 Then
    plateThickness = 4
    thicknessDisplay = 4
ElseIf Thickness = 0.5 Then
    plateThickness = 5
    thicknessDisplay = 5
ElseIf Thickness = 0.625 Then
    plateThickness = 6
    thicknessDisplay = 6
ElseIf Thickness = 0.75 Then
    plateThickness = 7
    thicknessDisplay = 7
ElseIf Thickness = 1 Then
    plateThickness = 8
    thicknessDisplay = 8
ElseIf Thickness = 1.25 Then
    plateThickness = 9
    thicknessDisplay = 9
ElseIf Thickness = 1.5 Then
    plateThickness = 10
    thicknessDisplay = 10
ElseIf Thickness = 2 Then
    plateThickness = 11
    thicknessDisplay = 11
ElseIf Thickness = 2.5 Then
    plateThickness = 12
    thicknessDisplay = 12
ElseIf Thickness = 3 Then
    plateThickness = 13
    thicknessDisplay = 13
End If

stockNumberValue = erpNumber(plateThickness)
iProperties.Value("Project", "Stock Number") = stockNumberValue
```

Here are the results I get if the user types in let's say .5:

Stock Number: PC0003

Description:  3/16" X 12" X 5" 100XF BURNOUT

it should say 1/2" X 12" X 5" 100XF BURNOUT

Comment: At the point that you read your array you haven't set thicknessDisplay. iProperties.Value("Project", "Description") = ..... needs to be after the If

Comment: @OldBoyCoder Thank you! That's all it was. I was thinking it was something to do with the order of the code, but I just couldn't see it. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point that you read your array you haven't set thicknessDisplay.

```
iProperties.Value("Project", "Description") = fractionDisplay(thicknessDisplay) & """" & " X " & Length & """" & " X " & Width & """" & " 100XF BURNOUT"
```

needs to be after the set of Ifs and Elseifs